# ArrayList<Integer> is not storing user-inputted integers in Java 8 (1.8)

Tags: java, arraylist, user-input

*EDIT - SOLVED: After instantiating the `Scanner Object`, I used a delimiter as follows:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("");
```

Prior to this, I did try a delimiter that looked something like this (the exact code is available on Stack Overflow):

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\p{javaWhitespace}");
```

...but it didn't work very well.

Thank you, everyone. If you're having this very same issue, try the first delimiter. If it doesn't work, upgrade your JDK to 13 then try it again.

Ok, my goal is to have a user input a credit card number which I would then like to store in an ArrayList of Integers and subsequently pass this list to my functions which will perform the Luhn algorithm in order to validate the provided number. Once the user presses Enter, the processing begins. This is a console application, nothing fancy.

Everything works beautifully...except the user-input part. None of the user-input is being stored into the declared ArrayList. I've inserted a print message to give me the size of the list just after the pertinent while-loop and....yep, 0. I also pass this list into a custom `lengthChecker(ArrayList<Integer> list){}` function subsequent to the relevant while-loop and it's printing my custom error-message.

I have declared local int variables within the scope of the while-loop and that wasn't helping much. I have tried getting the user's input as Strings and storing them in an `ArrayList<String> list;` then parsing the input but that didn't work very well (especially as I need the Enter key to behave as a delimiter such that the next steps can take place)

Anyways, here is the code to the function in question. Am I missing something obvious or should I just quit programming?

```
    public void userInput() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Please input the card-number to be checked then press Enter: ");    

        while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {

            list.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("Length of list: " + list.size());


        listLengthChecker(list);
        scanner.close();

  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not see the issue. I tested this code locally and it adds the integer successfully into arraylist. I had to comment out listLengthChecker(list) though.

Comment: The code is okay. What exactly do you type as input?

Comment: @rootkonda, thank you.

Comment: @mayamar, thank you, I'm inputting integers into the console via keyboard then pressing Enter to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full context on all the code you've written to be able to solve your problem, but I can guess at what's going on. If you want to run any user I/O (such as the scanner), it must occur within the `main` method. I can only assume that you run your `userInput()` function within the `main` method in your class. However, because your `userInput()` function doesn't have the `static` keyword in its definition, it can't be accessed without initialising an object of the class - but as far as I can tell from your code, there is no object that the method could refer to. Add the `static` keyword (i.e. initialise the method as `public static void userInput()`) to be able to run the function as you intend.

As for the while loop - there's a small chance that this is a difference in Java versions (I use Java 11), but `while(scanner.hasNextInt())` won't stop being true at the end of your line or when you press enter - only when you insert something (such as a character) that cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: Thank you, James L. I've edited my original post and have included all of my code but I've omitted my versions of the Luhn algorithm. Interesting insights pertinent to Java 11 (kind of scary), and running I/O exclusively in main. As of now, I am calling userInput() in the constructor of the CardValidator card - I've also tried calling this function using the class instance of CardValidator that I've declared in the main method but I'm getting the same results, unfortunately.
Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
This while loop untill you enter any non integer value.
You finished entering all the integer values and then your program will print your list elements.

Comment: Thank you, @busetekin, I very much appreciate that you put this together to help out. Thanks again.